# Windbg: SOS.dll: !gcroot: DOMAIN(xxx):HANDLE(Pinned):Does it really mean object is pinned?

Tags: windbg, sos

The documentation on the SOS.dll Windbg extension seems sparse.  After issuing a !gcroot <address>, I am getting something containing the following:

```
DOMAIN(XXX):HANDLE(Pinned):XXX:Root:XXX(System.Object[])->
```

Does "HANDLE(Pinned)" *really* mean there is a GCHandle of type GCHandleType.Pinned that is rooting this object?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably not pinned, per se, but rather is probably a static reference.  Take a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2005/11/25/497016.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does mean the object is pinned. Now you have to find *what* is pinning the object and preventing it from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Another possible value instead of pinned is WeakLn, which means it will be garbage collected on the next sweep.

Answer (score -1):

I know that Karel Zikmund, MSFT Moderator at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/e52936b4-15c4-434f-91b9-4640df66d0c6 says "yes."  But I'm looking for extra opinions, insight, etc.  Thanks!